# Angular 2+: Child components ts variable changes but UI does not show changed value?

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a child `TestComponent` component as follows:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { ApiService } from '../../../api.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-test',
  templateUrl: './test.component.html'
})
export class TestComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private apiService: ApiService) { }

  testDisplayMessage = 'No data to show';

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  getMessage(param: string) {
    this.callingTest = true;
    this.apiService.getTest( param ).subscribe( data => {
      this.setTestDisplayMessage( data );
      this.callingTest = false;
    }, err => {
      console.log( JSON.stringify( err ) );
      this.setTestDisplayMessage( 'Failed to get data' );
      this.callingTest = false;
    } );
  }

  setTestDisplayMessage( message: string ) {
    this.testDisplayMessage = message;
  }
}
```

contents of `test.component.html`

```
<p style="padding: 10px;">{{ testDisplayMessage }}</p>
```

Use in parent componet :

Trigger JS Code in parent component on button click,

```
import { TestComponent } from './test/test.component';
....

.....
@Component({
  providers: [ TestComponent ],
  templateUrl: 'parent.component.html'
})
export class ParentComponent implements OnInit {
  ...
  constructor(private testComponent: TestComponent) { }
  ...
  // Button on parent template triggers this method
  getMessage() {
    this.testComponent.getMessage('Hello');
  }
  ...
}
```

Html tag added in parent component,

```
<app-test></app-test>
```

When I debugged above code trigger point, call to `setTestDisplayMessage()` happens the field `testDisplayMessage` in `TestComponent` gets changed but UI shows the old message `'No data to show'`, why is the message on change does not reflect on UI template? Or this is not the way it is supposed to get used? Shall I use `@Input`

**Update:**

Based on the pointers given in the following answers as well as comment sections, I changed my component as `@ViewChild` so in above parent component instead of passing the child component as an argument to constructor I declared it as child component using `@ViewChild`, so code changes as follows,

**Earlier wrong code**

```
constructor(private testComponent: TestComponent) { }
```

**Solution**

```
@ViewChild(TestComponent)
testComponent: TestComponent;
```

I found [this article](https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-viewchild/) useful.

Comment: `@Input` would work here, have your testDisplayMessage be an input variable, and in your parent component have a `message` variable. In the parent template, `<app-test [testDisplayMessage]=message>` will bind the child message with your parent message

Comment: You are injecting "a" `TestComponent` which is not the `TestComponent` created via `<app-test></app-test>` of parent template. You need to use `@ViewChild` decorator to get reference to child component.

Comment: @HarunYılmaz This gave me a pointer, thanks for the reply

Answer (score 3):

Use `@ViewChild()`

In html file:

```
<app-test #childComp></app-test>
```

In parent component.ts file

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
....

.....
@Component( {
templateUrl: 'parent.component.html'
} )
export class ParentComponent implements OnInit {

@viewChild('childComp') childComp: any;
constructor() { }
...
// Button on parent template triggers this method
getMessage() {
   this.childComp.getMessage('Hello');
}
...
}
```

Comment: What is the meaning of `private testComponent: TestComponent` in constructor? And if you set the type of `ViewChild` to `ElementRef`, won't it throw `getMessage is not a function` error?

Comment: @Chirag This did not work for me but gave me a pointer, thanks for the reply

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**

Based on the pointers given in the following answers as well as comment sections, I changed my component as `@ViewChild` so in above parent component instead of passing the child component as an argument to constructor I declared it as child component using `@ViewChild`, so code changes as follows,

**Earlier wrong code**

```
constructor(private testComponent: TestComponent) { }
```

**Solution**

```
@ViewChild(TestComponent)
testComponent: TestComponent;
```

I found [this article](https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-viewchild/) useful.

Answer (score -1):

definitely use @Input() but on set method

```
@Input()
set someProperty(value) {
  // do some code
}
```

now every time you pass new value here, code will run

Comment: don't know why here is downvote - here is official documentation how to communicate between components https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction

Answer (score -1):

basically, your approach is wrong, please use Input() or Services to share data between components.

however, if you want to make ur code work, the below **may** work

1. import change detector

   constructor(**private cdRef: ChangeDetectorRef**) {
           }

note: import reference ->
 import { ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';

2. execute detect change after the value is updated

   ```
   setTestDisplayMessage( message: string ) {
       this.testDisplayMessage = message;
       this.cdRef.detectChanges();
     }
   ```

I hope this helps

Comment: @Ipradhap This did not work for me but gave me a pointer, thanks for the reply